# Magento 2 - Save custom entity data failed

Tags: magento2, model, custom

I followed [this](https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-module-part-1-setup/) post to create my custom entity.
Now I registered an observer on the "customer_register_success" event and tried to save additional data in my custom entity. That doesn't work and I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtension::save()

What is wrong?

Here is my code of the observer:

```
public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, //log injection
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory $customerExtensionFactory
) {

    $this->_logger = $logger;

    $this->_logger->debug('AfterCustomerSaveObserver_Constructor_Begin');

    $this->_customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->_customerExtensionFactory = $customerExtensionFactory;

    $this->_logger->debug('AfterCustomerSaveObserver_Constructor_End');
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

    $this->_logger->debug('AfterCustomerSaveObserver_Execute_Begin');

    try { 

        //Get Customer object
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $customer = $event->getCustomer();      

        //Get Controller
        $controller = $event->getAccountController();

        //Get Additional Data from Controller
        $userName = $controller->getRequest()->getParam("user_name", "");

        //Create Customer Extension object
        $model = $this->_customerExtensionFactory->create(['customer_id' => $customer->getId()]);

        //Set User Name
        $model->setUserName($userName);

        //Save Customer Extension object
        $model->save();
    } 
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        $this->_logger->critical($e);
        $this->_logger->debug('exception');
    } 

    $this->_logger->debug('AfterCustomerSaveObserver_Execute_End');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CustomerExtension` is not a model and thus doesn't have any ability to save itself, it is basically just a data container for extension attributes on for the `CustomerInterface`. You would need to utilize the `CustomerRepository` in order to save the data.

In working with extension attributes you may have defined in a `extension_attributes.xml` [more on DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html), here are some of the pieces involved:

```
// Get the entity Interface from the entity Repository
$entity = $this->entityRepositoryInterface->get($entityId);

// Get existing ExtensionAttributes or create one
$entityExtension = $entity->getExtensionAttributes();
if ($entityExtension == null) {
    $entityExtension = $this->entityExtensionFactory->create();
}

// Set a value on your attribute
$entityExtension->setMyAttribute($value);

// Set the ExtensionAttributes back to the entity
$entity->setExtensionAttributes($entityExtension);

// Save the entity using the repository
$this->entityRepository->save($entity);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I added an Extension Module named CustomerExtension. There was the Problem...